# Proof of a theorem in model theory and examples of infinite relational theory

Tags: relations, model-theory

Suppose $L$ is a first-order language. I'd like to know how to prove the following result (or any resource that contains such a proof).

**Theorem**: If $M$ is a countable $L$-structure that is ($\omega$-)homogeneous in a finite relational language, then $M$ is $\omega$-categorical.

I think that most theories are of finite relations. For example, set theory has one relation of $"\in"$. But I am not sure how finite relational language is used in the proof. So I also want to know examples of infinite relational theory.

Comment: Are you familiar with back-and-forth arguments?

Comment: Let $T=Th(M)$ and consider two countable models $A,B\models T$. We want to build an isomorphism between them using a back-and-forth argument. All we need to do, then, is *prove the "forth" and "back" lemmas*. Together, these say that given a pair of tuples $\overline{c}\in A,\overline{d}\in B$ of the same length and satisfying the same atomic types in their respective structures, we can $(i)$ for any $a\in A$ find a $b\in B$ such that $\overline{c}a$ and $\overline{d}b$ satisfy the same atomic types in $A$ and $B$ respectively and $(ii)$ the same but with the roles of $a/A$ and $b/B$ reversed.

Comment: Now in general, proving these lemmas for a pair of structures may be difficult (or impossible). But in this case we have a very strong hypothesis to work with: **homogeneity**. Do you see how to apply homogeneity to get the lemma(s) we need? (At a particular step you'll also need to use finite-language-ness, but that's really more of a technicality in my opinion, at least as far as first-understanding goes.)

Comment: To see why finite language is necessary, consider the structure $M$ whose domain is the natural numbers and which has a unary predicate $U_i$ with $U_i^M=\{i\}$. This is homogeneous - indeed, any two distinct tuples have distinct atomic types - but it's not $\aleph_0$-categorical. I'll leave it to you to see where the "obvious" back-and-forth argument breaks down (you'll want to carefully write all of the steps out), since it really is a good exercise.

Comment: "I think that most theories are of finite relations" - not really, no. The combinatorial ones typically ale relational, but a lot of the interesting ones are algebraic. You can code them as relational structures, but then you typically lose ultrahomogeneity (even if you have it to begin with). Ultrahomogeneous structures in finite relational language generally are not very expressive when it comes to algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homogeneity (in its appropriate form, the term is used in a couple different ways in my experience) is a great tool for proving the hypothesis of what should be called the "key lemma of back-and-forth arguments:"

> Suppose $A,B$ are two countable structures in the same relational language satisfying the following properties for all pairs of tuples $\overline{a}\in A,\overline{b}\in B$ which satisfy the same types in their respective structures:
>
> - **(Forth)** For all $c\in A$ there is a $d\in B$ such that $\overline{a}c$ and $\overline{b}d$ satisfy the same types in $A$ and $B$ respectively.
> - **(Back)** For all $d\in B$ there is a $c\in A$ such that $\overline{a}c$ and $\overline{b}d$ satisfy the same types in $A$ and $B$ respectively.
>
> Then $A\cong B$.

It is precisely in verifying the hypotheses of this lemma, though, that the **finiteness** of the language is required. I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out exactly what the issue is, but to motivate things here's a simple counterexample: let our language consist of a single unary predicate $U_i$ for each natural number $i$, let $A$ be the natural numbers with $U_i^A=\{i\}$, and let $B$ be $A$ together with a fresh element $*$ not lying in any of the $U_i^B$s. Then $A$ and $B$ are countable, homogeneous, and elementarily equivalent, but the **back** hypothesis of the lemma fails immediately since there is nothing in $A$ that can be safely paired with $*$ in $B$.